# Laravel Scout with AWS OpenSearch illegal_argument_exception when searching on model

Tags: laravel, opensearch, laravel-scout

I have installed the [zingimmick/laravel-scout-opensearch](https://github.com/zingimmick/laravel-scout-opensearch) driver for Scout on my Laravel 10 application and manually synced a few records.

I was not able to use the `php artisan scout:import` command because my table does not have an auto-incrementing `id` primary key, so I've loaded up a few records like this (for testing):

```
Asset::query()
    ->limit(50)
    ->get()
    ->searchable();
```

`Asset` model looks like this:

```
class Asset extends Model
{
    use Searchable;

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'policy_id',
        'asset_id',
        'fingerprint',
        'asset_name',
    ];

    public function searchableAs(): string
    {
        return 'assets_index';
    }

    public function getScoutKey(): string
    {
        return $this->policy_id . $this->asset_id;
    }
}
```

I can see the data in the OpenSearch dashboard under manage indices:

[image]

Now that the data is loaded, when ever I try to search by this `Asset` model like this:

```
    $result = \App\Models\Asset::search('some value here')->get();
    dd($result->toArray());
```

I get this error:

> Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [id] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory.

Here's the full error: https://pastebin.com/raw/VTsK9eBd

I am new to both Laravel Scout and AWS OpenSearch, any ideas what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to execute a fuzzy search like this:

```
    $builder = \App\Models\Asset::search(
        'some value here',
        static function ($client, $query, $params) {
            $params['body']['query'] = [
                'multi_match' => [
                    'query' => $query,
                    'fuzziness' => 'AUTO',
                    'fields' => [
                        'policy_id',
                        'asset_id',
                        'fingerprint',
                        'asset_name^3',
                    ],
                ],
            ];
            return $client->search($params);
        }
    );

    dd($builder->take(5)->raw());
```

I am not sure why all the example for Laravel Scout says you can simply do `Model::search('some value here')->get()`